# Firebase Cloud Functions, cost on Realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm wondering about how does Cloud Functions cost scales on data write/delete. On the pricing page, under Cloud Functions, I can only understand the amount of invocations. Let's say I want to periodically (twice a day) delete certain nodes under "users" nodes, and there are many users. Would this cost extra compare with deleting a single node?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Cloud Functions and Realtime Database have completely different billing structures.  You will have to add up the individual usage of those two products to get a final cost.  The cost of one does not necessarily impact the other.  Accessing Realtime Database from a Cloud Function does not fundamentally cost any more or less than the same access from a web or mobile client.

Comment: Hi, @DougStevenson.  So when I use CF to delete Realtime database data, the cost counts from both RT and CF right? I thought it was only for CF.

Comment: Database access isn't free from Cloud Functions.  Your function will incur the costs of the delete from the perspective of the database.